# Second level cache in JPA using Entity manager for native queries as well as for JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, caching

I have implemented second level cache using jpa through EntityManager and using java configuration for it. I referred the following link http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache. I am not getting any error but also my Entity’s Data Is not Cached. Please help:)

I have provided all the required configuration to enable L2 cache in the application and here is my code for configuration:-

This is my application.properties file -

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode = ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_class = net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
```

This is my entity class -

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "booking")
```

This is what I am getting in console log of my application that is every time I am hitting the same request, query is hitting the database at every request. That’s why concluded L2 cache is not involved.

```
Hibernate: SELECT booking.BId,booking.calledDate Called, booking.calleduser Caller, booking.callerNotes, booking.Title, booking.FName, booking.ScName, booking.bookingPhase, Training.TName, booking.TrDate, booking.SubmitDateTime, trlocation.TrLocation trTrl, booking.STATUS, booking.DelegNum, booking.Tel, booking.Email,booking.Notes FROM(SELECT booking.* FROM booking booking WHERE booking.SubmitDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND booking.SId > 0 ORDER BY booking.BId DESC LIMIT 1) booking LEFT JOIN training Training ON booking.Training = Training.TId LEFT JOIN confirmation ON booking.Bid = confirmation.Bid LEFT JOIN trlocation ON booking.TrLocation = trlocation.TrLId LEFT JOIN invoice ON booking.BId =invoice.BId AND invoice.PayReceiveBy='' AND invoice.Id='-1' LEFT JOIN couriertracking ON booking.BId = couriertracking.bId LEFT JOIN salesperson ON booking.SId = salesperson.SId AND booking.SId > 0 
----------the data is NOT cached
Hibernate: SELECT booking.BId,booking.calledDate Called, booking.calleduser Caller, booking.callerNotes, booking.Title, booking.FName, booking.ScName, booking.bookingPhase, Training.TName, booking.TrDate, booking.SubmitDateTime, trlocation.TrLocation trTrl, booking.STATUS, booking.DelegNum, booking.Tel, booking.Email,booking.Notes FROM(SELECT booking.* FROM booking booking WHERE booking.SubmitDateTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND booking.SId > 0 ORDER BY booking.BId DESC LIMIT 1) booking LEFT JOIN training Training ON booking.Training = Training.TId LEFT JOIN confirmation ON booking.Bid = confirmation.Bid LEFT JOIN trlocation ON booking.TrLocation = trlocation.TrLId LEFT JOIN invoice ON booking.BId =invoice.BId AND invoice.PayReceiveBy='' AND invoice.Id='-1' LEFT JOIN couriertracking ON booking.BId = couriertracking.bId LEFT JOIN salesperson ON booking.SId = salesperson.SId AND booking.SId > 0 
----------the data is NOT cached
```

Comment: You mean you have ENABLED second level cache. IMPLEMENTED is something else entirely. So you execute some code, and get some result. So share that code, share what the LOG says when you execute that code. Share why you think the L2 cache is not involved.

Comment: Please review my question again, I have provided my code and LOG there.

Comment: I don't think I follow. You say you conclude L2 cache is not working because the query is hitting the database each time. What does one have to do with the other? Have you enabled query cache for that particular query? Is the query the result to a call to `EntityManager.find`? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled query cache for that particular query. I am doing something like this - 
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(" ");

List<Object[]> bookingLists = query.setParameter(1, 
bId).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true).getResultList();

return bookingLists;

Comment: Caching native query `Object[]` results is not a common use case and I'm not sure if Hibernate handles it properly. I can suggest two things: (1) try removing the deprecated `hibernate.cache.provider_class` property (`SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory` does not implement `CacheProvider`, anyway), and (2) try returning the query result as a list of entities (using `EntityManager.createNamedQuery("...", Booking.class)`.